# Is there a feasible way to insulate one half of a single room?

Tags: insulation

I live with my partner in an apartment (I'd say our room is roughly 300~ sqft) and there's a bit of an issue with room temperature that we can't really put down. They love it cold and I prefer it more on the warmer end. Compromise is typically hard to think up of just because of overall body temperature differences and preferences, and either end not really wanting to make the other overly uncomfortable. Since we rent, it's rather difficult to think of any solutions that might be permanent without damaging the area.

Does anyone have any suggestions or maybe has anyone experienced this before and applied some solution to maybe fix both ends? I was thinking of a room divider, but unsure of how well that would work.

Comment: You could wear unseasonably warm clothes.  Or maybe just a rakish watch cap.  A time tested solution to wanting to be more warm.  Also: thick socks and slippers.

Comment: You say "partner" but describe a solution, a divider, that implies you would be living fairly separately.  I think it would help if your question was more specific.   My partner and I like different sleeping temperatures and we have a solution for that while in the same bed.  But if we are watching TV or eating together, we have to compromise.  And dress differently.  We live in a house so when we are working or doing separate things we can be in separate rooms.   If you describe a more specific situation where you want a solution, it would help to produce more useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think a room divider is a great idea, but make sure it extends nearly to the ceiling and completely seals the edges, to the floor , etc.

Because you’re renting I presume you do not have the option of moving your heating supply air unit, but you may be able to move the vanes and direct them away from your end (and to the other side of the room divider).

If you let the air blow on them it acts like a fan. A fan doesn’t cool the air it merely blows the same temperature as air around. However, when air blows across your skin it tends to cool the air on the skin. The air temperature will be the same at each end of the room, it will just seem cooler when the air blows directly on them n

Answer (score 0):

A dehumidifier might help.  Feeling cold/hot isn't just about temperature.  Humidity plays a role as well.  Dry air makes it feel colder, humid air makes it feel warmer.  You could try a dehumidifier with a warmer room.  The person that likes it cold exposes as much skin as possible, the direct contact with the dry air will cause sweat to evaporate faster and they will feel cooler (especially with a fan).  The one that likes it hot covers their skin (pants long sleeves) to prevent evaporation and is insulated more.

I don't think separate rooms is an ideal solution for a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Set the air temperature just slightly too warm for the person who likes it cooler. Then, the person who wants to be warmer adds another layer or two of clothes.

Depending on the relationship between the "partners" (what a useless, yet so politically correct word), if the cooler weather person is still too warm, (s)he can take additional clothing off.

Can't fathom how this is that difficult...

Answer (score 0):

Localized infrared heat might be a solution. Panel heaters directed at your favorite sitting area could heat your furniture and the air around it without overheating the rest of the room. Couple that with electric blankets as furniture covers and some nice slippers and you'd probably be happy.